# Facing ERROR "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in Hadoop while running the multiple mappers parallely in single node machine

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am using Hadoop on a single node machine in Local Mode. When I am running files sequentially then everything is working file. However, when I run mappers parallelly I am facing the error "**org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job:run(560) | job_local131593030_0008 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**". I have done some research on this and found two property "mapreduce.map.memory.mb" and "mapred.child.java.opts" that used to increase the physical and heap memory for the mappers but this did not work in my case for Local mode. Could anyone please give me the suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: `mapred.child.java.opts` is deprecated. What does your job actual do? Why does it need more memory? Why do you need Hadoop if you only have a single machine, and why cant you use Spark rather than MapReduce?

Comment: Actually, we already have set up of application on MapReduce to process a large number of files on local mode. Previously all the splits of a single file were processing sequentially. With one property I have achieved the parallel processing of splits but getting OutOfMemory issue when splits run parallel. Now, I am looking to increase the memory.

Comment: Alright. Just letting you know Spark can use the same InputFormat / InputSplit classes you've defined. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to you Spark. Anyone, how can help me with this?

Comment: Not allowed by a teacher? I can tell you from 5 years in Hadoop jobs that no one actually writes Mapreduce... Anyways, you need to increase the YARN container sizes. To what number is unknown, but larger than what it currently is. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.7/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml